# Numerix CrossAsset cost and coverage

Tags: software

Does anyone have an approximate idea how much Numerix CrossAsset (for excel) costs for a single user?

I'm interested in capabilities and coverage for IR/credit exotic/semi-exotic.

Comment: Best is probably to contact their sales and ask for an indication.

Comment: Apparently the person who posted the question is not in a position to contact the sales directly, otherwise one would have done so. For example, one may work of a competitive firm and would be curious to know how much a company like Numerix charge for certain services. Numerix sales would never answer such an enquiry!